# IMAP_OPEN function with POP3 only return emails of the year 2016?

Tags: php, imap, pop3

Why `imap_open` function with `POP3` return emails of the year 2016? The emails range is year(2014.2020). With `IMAP` connection it's working correctly.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO!  And please check this out. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: As far your question is concerned, can you show us the code?